# How to get field name from a SQL statement using c#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to retrieve field names from a SQL statement. For example, if I have:-

```
SELECT a, tbl.b, [tbl.s] 
FROM tbl
```

I'd like to retrieve::

- a
- tbl.b
- [tbl.s]

I'd need to do it via any database object.

Comment: So you're saying you want to be able to parse field names out of a string containing any kind of SQL statement?

Comment: Do you execute the statement?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [SqlDataReader Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) you can do:

```
Reader.GetName(columnNumber)
```

and that will return the column name.